# Insert parameters with array in ORACLE using stored procedure

Tags: c#, reactjs, oracle

I have below parameters from reactjs and I'm passing it to C#, then it will pass to Oracle stored procedure for INSERT. My question is on Oracle Stored Procedure, how will I able to insert it to table as multiple row, depends on the value of Array from the column2 with same ID.

```
{
  ID: 2,
  DEP_ID: [4,5,6]
}
```

I want to save it to tbl_testing with below result.

`tbl_testing`

```
ID | DEP_ID
2  | 4
2  | 5
2  | 6
```

Comment: What is the actual question? You do not know how to pass an array as parameter to Oracle's procedure or you do not know how to use that array inside a procedure? Note: Oracle has no native array datatype, but a [collection](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/lnpls/plsql-collections-and-records.html#GUID-7E9034D5-0D33-43A1-9012-918350FE148C).

Comment: @astentx, my question is on how to use the array inside a procedure. You can also include the question how to pass array as parameter, to make sure I'm doing it right. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One simple way to achieve this is using a Procedure with regular expression functions to split the array into its different parts

Demo

```
create table dptos ( v1 number, v2 number );

create or replace procedure insert_table ( p1 in varchar2 , p2 in varchar2 ) 
is 
v_counter pls_integer := regexp_count (p2, ',') + 1; 
v_record  pls_integer;
begin 
for var in 1..v_counter 
loop
    if var = 1 
    then
        v_record := regexp_substr( p2, '[^,]+', 1 , 1 );
        insert into dptos ( v1 , v2 ) values ( p1 , v_record );
    elsif var > 1 and var <= v_counter 
    then 
        v_record := regexp_substr( p2, '[^,]+', 1 , var );
        insert into dptos ( v1 , v2 ) values ( p1 , v_record );
    end if;
end loop; 
commit;
end;
/

SQL> exec insert_table ( 2 , '4,5,6' ) ;

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> select * from dptos ;

        V1         V2
---------- ----------
         2          4
         2          5
         2          6

SQL>
```

Of course, it works for the purpose of your example as long as you can call the procedure in that way using the values of the array.